# Selecting minimum date from postgres table using group by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with data as company name, employee name, leave days. I want to extract the company name and min date for an employee. For this I am using this query

```
select companyname, min(date) from table where companyname = 'apple' and employeename = 'ABC'
```

This query however fails saying that column "tablename.companyname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

I did try using companyname in group by clause along with date but this gave me a lot of values instead of one minimum date.

Can any one figure out how to do this without adding to complexities.

I did figure out the solution. However, I didn't quite understand why it asked me to use companyname in the group by clause.

Comment: What was the query you used with the group by? Posting that will help people troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: You wanted a minimum date for a Companyname  so you would want the data grouped by the Companyname and then fetch the minimum in the list. hence the Group by CompanyName :). The compiler does not care that your where clause restricts it to one CompanyName. As far as it is concerned if you have an aggregate function on a column and a column with no aggregate function. you need to tell it what to do with the column you did not put the aggregate function on.

Comment: @TMNT2014 : Okay. Understood. Is this exhibited only by postgres or other DBMS also?

Comment: As far as I know TSQL and Oracle behave the same way.

Answer (score 4):

It is standard SQL requirement that you [`GROUP BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP) columns that are not aggregated.

```
SELECT companyname, min(date) AS min_date
FROM   tbl
WHERE  companyname = 'apple'
AND    employeename = 'ABC'
GROUP  BY companyname;
```

You can use a positional reference to shorten the code in Postgres:

```
...
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Or drop the pre-determined column `companyname` from the `SELECT` list. Then you don't need `GROUP BY` either:

```
SELECT min(date) AS min_date
FROM   tbl
WHERE  companyname = 'apple'
AND    employeename = 'ABC';
```

Comment: Or maybe they want `SELECT companyname, min(date) AS min_date … GROUP BY companyname ORDER BY min_date LIMIT 1;`. Of course, in that case no grouping is needed